# After changing action bar height, the homeasupindicator not vertical

Tags: android

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/homeasup_back</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_orange</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/ActionBarMenuTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="height">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="icon">@mipmap/icon</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
</style>
```

If I do not change `ActionBar` height,it's correct!
I can't post images!
Please help me！ Thanks！